# merge of keras model, input output problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, merge, concatenation

I want to use an already trainned model to build a new one in 2 step.

consider already trained model as model_109 acording to the figure with a first layer of LSTM (Extracteur_LSTM) and a second of dense and a last one of 1 dense output.

my goal is to feed model_109 and get the output (output1).
and
as second model, use only the head of model_109 (Extracteur_LSTM) output, merge it to output1 to feed a new model of dense.
My final output is model_109 AND output of the new dense model.

```
tensor_input = Input(shape=(Xn.shape[1], Xn.shape[2]), name='input2')

prev_model = load_model('model_109.h5')

out_prev_mod = prev_model(tensor_input)
merge_1 = Concatenate()([prev_model.layers[1].output, out_prev_mod])

xy2 = Dense(60+1, activation='softsign',
                kernel_initializer= initializers.he_uniform(), 
                name='DenseOutput2')(merge_1)
xy2 = Dropout(rate = 02])(xy2)
    
out2 = Dense(1, activation='linear',
                kernel_initializer= initializers.he_uniform(), 
                name='Output2')(xy2)


output = Concatenate()([out_prev_mod, out2])
    
model = Model(inputs=[prev_model.input, tensor_input], outputs=[output])


optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=params['learningRate']) # optimizer = RMSprop, 
            'Adagrad', 'adam' 'adadelta'
            early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=autres_param['patience'] )
    if chckpts == True:
        filepath = 'models/' + nom_exp + "_best-weights.h5"
        checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath= filepath, monitor='val_loss', 
                     mode='min', save_best_only=True)
        cllBck = [early_stopping, checkpoint]
    else:
        cllBck = [early_stopping]
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=params['loss'])

    
    history = model.fit([Xn], yn, validation_split = 
              autres_param['valid_ratio'],
              epochs=autres_param['epochs'], shuffle = autres_param['shuffle'],
              batch_size = autres_param['batch'], verbose=2, callbacks=cllBck)
```

In the graph, input1 and input is the same and Extracteur_LSTM is a copy of Model_109 first layer

[image: graph of this code]

finaly I get this error...

ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[[[8.19255325e-04,

Comment: try to define your model in this way Model(inputs=tensor_input, outputs=output) and simply fit in this way model.fit(Xn, yn, ....)

Comment: This was my first trial but get this error... '''ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_27:0", shape=(None, 60, 7), dtype=float32) at layer "input". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: [] ''' maybe it is the good way and my true prob is on this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly nail it....

```
tensor_input = Input(shape=(Xn.shape[1], Xn.shape[2]), name='input')
```

prev_model = load_model('model_109.h5')

```
# keep head of model
model2= Model(inputs=prev_model .input, outputs=prev_model.layers[-2].output) 

new_mod = Sequential()
new_mod.add(prev_model )

# Freeze trained Layer 0 
new_mod.layers[0].trainable = False

## add/replace layer
new_mod.add(Dense(params['unitsDense1'], activation=params['activationDenseOutput'],
                  kernel_initializer= initializers.he_uniform(),
                  name='DenseOutput1'))

new_mod.add(Dense(1, activation=params['activationDenseOutput'],
                  kernel_initializer= initializers.he_uniform(),
                  name='DenseOutput1'))
```